# Why does the ASP.NET WebApi clear out Identity if no route match?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, owin

I am trying to setup a web api with signalr and during the process I noticed this oddity. I cannot seem to find a documented reason why the Identity on the OwinContext would be emptied out after there was no match on the web api route table. I put together a simple project to show this in action:

#### Startup

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Filters.Clear();
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AccessTokenFormat = new TokenFormatter(),
        AuthenticationType = "DummyAuth",
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = async (ctx) => ctx.Validated(ctx.Ticket),
            OnRequestToken = async (ctx) => ctx.Token = "111"
        }
    });
    appBuilder.Use<DebugMiddleware>("New Request", (Action<IOwinContext>)((IOwinContext ctx) => Console.WriteLine("End Request")));
    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    appBuilder.Use<DebugMiddleware>("Before WebApi");
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    appBuilder.Use<DebugMiddleware>("After WebApi");
    appBuilder.RunSignalR();
    appBuilder.Use<DebugMiddleware>("After SignalR");
    config.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

#### Dummy token formatter

```cs
public class TokenFormatter : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
        return "111";
    }
    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("DummyAuth");
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Bob"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob"));
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, null);
        return ticket;
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Value")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetValue()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

#### Hub

```cs
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hub.OnConnected Username: {new OwinContext(Context.Request.Environment).Authentication?.User?.Identity?.Name}");
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hub.OnDisconnected Username: {new OwinContext(Context.Request.Environment).Authentication?.User?.Identity?.Name}");
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

If I attempt to connect to a Hub (at the end of the pipeline) the OwinContext is no longer authenticated.
The output from each DebugMiddleware shows:

#### Output

```
> Start Request
Authenticated?: True
User: Bob
Before WebApi
Authenticated?: True
User: Bob
After WebApi
**Authenticated?: False** <- Why the change here?
**User:**
End Request
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

P.S. This same question is asked on the project's [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/119).<del>, but I have not got a response.</del> (**EDIT:** Getting help on now)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a result of assumptions made when building the ASP.NET Web API pipeline among other things. The full conversation is on the [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/119) link above. But to summarize:

> It's Just Wrong™️ not to restore the Principal.

Issue has been resolved on github and is scheduled for the next release. In the mean time if you find your self having this issue. There is a workaround, simply move your controllers onto a sub-route. This prevents the ASP pipeline from wiping out the Principle.

```
appBuilder.Map("api" app => {
   app.UseWebApi(config);
   // Principal no longer available the UseWebApi middleware 
};
appBuilder.RunSignalR(); // <- still has access to principal
```